# Validate contents of dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a method that accepts a dict as an input and does some formatting on the dict.

I would like to ensure the dict contains the required entries before starting the formatting. At the moment I have the code

```
if not ('email' in payload and
        'renewal_date' in payload and
        'username' in payload
        ):
    raise InvalidDictContentsError
```

Some of the dicts will have 15 or so items in it so it gets very long. Is there a more elegant way of verifying the dict?

Comment: Yes, you can use `set` methods to test a bunch of keys at once.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Sure that works (I assume that the `I` is a typo and you meant `l`). But a `dict.keys()` View object is set-like and you can use subset or superset testing on it, which is faster than testing items one by one, especially if you're testing against a fixed set like `{'email', 'renewal_date', 'username'}`